# Add attribute to content title

Tags: views, nodes

I'd like to add a custom attribute into the title element whenever a particular content type is displayed, whether as an individual node or through a view (specifically when displaying 'full content').  How do I do this?

I'm using Drupal 7.

Comment: What does "custom tag" mean?

Comment: Sorry, I meant attribute.  I've edited my question.

Comment: did you try field.tpl?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could modify the field.tpl like monymirza suggested. But you may want to use `hook_preprocess_field(&$vars)` and target the title element within the `$vars` array.

Use that function in your theme and you may view the content/structure of the `$vars` array with `dsm($vars)` from the [devel module](http://drupal.org/project/devel).